# addEventListener does not seem to add class to another element

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a rock scissors paper game, and the function checkUserChoice works.  The function assignRock, when connected to the addEventListner, does not. But if I call the function assignRock(); it does work. Not sure why the "click" does not seem to be working.

```js
const rockChoice = document.querySelector(".rockChoice");
const scissorsChoice = document.querySelector(".scissorsChoice");
const paperChoice = document.querySelector(".paperChoice");

const addIsRock = document.querySelector(".addIsRock");

function assignRock() {
  rockChoice.classList.add("isRock");
}
addIsRock.addEventListener("click", assignRock);

var userChoice;

function checkUserChoice() {
  if (rockChoice.classList.contains("isRock")) {
    userChoice = "rock";
  } else if (scissorsChoice.classList.contains("isScissors")) {
    userChoice = "scissors";
  } else if (paperChoice.classList.contains("isPaper")) {
    userChoice = "paper";
  }
}

checkUserChoice();

console.log('the user choice is ' + userChoice);
```

```css
.rockChoice {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.scissorsChoice {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.paperChoice {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.addIsRock {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rockChoice"><a href="#" class="addIsRock">Rock</a></div>
<div class="scissorsChoice"><a href="#">Scissors</a></div>
<div class="paperChoice"><a href="#">Paper</a></div>
```

Comment: What makes you say `checkUserChoice()` works? it logs `undefined`. Do you just mean that it's called?

Comment: Oh right, so if I add .isRock manually to <div class="rockChoice"> it will console log correctly. But I want .isRock to be added by a user with a click. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you don't initialize `userChoice`... I think there are a few things going on here. I think what you intend to do is return a value from `checkUserChoice()` and log that?

Comment: By the time you click on the link, checkUserChoice has already been invoked and finished executing, so it doesn't "see" the value set by the click handler. Perhaps you can call checkUserChoice on click of another button which you click after clicking on "Rock"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think your problem is essentially that you expect things to run in a different order than they are currently running (which for at least some parts of your code is not at all). I hope that the code I have written makes what is happening clearer, but if not let me know.

```js
const rockChoice = document.querySelector(".rockChoice");
const scissorsChoice = document.querySelector(".scissorsChoice");
const paperChoice = document.querySelector(".paperChoice");

const addIsRock = document.querySelector(".addIsRock");

function assignRock() {
  rockChoice.classList.add("isRock");
}
addIsRock.addEventListener("click", assignRock);

function checkUserChoice() {
  var userChoice;
  if (rockChoice.classList.contains("isRock")) {
    userChoice = "rock";
  } else if (scissorsChoice.classList.contains("isScissors")) {
    userChoice = "scissors";
  } else if (paperChoice.classList.contains("isPaper")) {
    userChoice = "paper";
  }
  return userChoice;
}

console.log('the user choice is ' + checkUserChoice()); //this happens when the page loads

//Click the rock button here (within 10 seconds), so the click event takes

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('the user choice is ' + checkUserChoice()); //this will log that the user choice is 'rock'
}, 10000);
```

```css
.rockChoice {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.scissorsChoice {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.paperChoice {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.addIsRock {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rockChoice"><a href="#" class="addIsRock">Rock</a></div>
<div class="scissorsChoice"><a href="#">Scissors</a></div>
<div class="paperChoice"><a href="#">Paper</a></div>
```

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. Keep at it. Looks like you're writing good code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add checkUserChoice() as an event as well, and move the console log into that method. It's assigning rock as the userChoice value just fine, it's only your feedback to view the change that isn't being executed.

```js
const rockChoice = document.querySelector(".rockChoice");
const scissorsChoice = document.querySelector(".scissorsChoice");
const paperChoice = document.querySelector(".paperChoice");

const addIsRock = document.querySelector(".addIsRock");

function assignRock() {
  rockChoice.classList.add("isRock");
}
addIsRock.addEventListener("click", assignRock);

var userChoice;

function checkUserChoice() {
  if (rockChoice.classList.contains("isRock")) {
    userChoice = "rock";
  } else if (scissorsChoice.classList.contains("isScissors")) {
    userChoice = "scissors";
  } else if (paperChoice.classList.contains("isPaper")) {
    userChoice = "paper";
  }
  //Moved into method so it's logged every time method is invoked
  console.log('the user choice is ' + userChoice);
}

//Add check as an event following the assign event
addIsRock.addEventListener("click", checkUserChoice);
```

```css
.rockChoice {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.scissorsChoice {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.paperChoice {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.addIsRock {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rockChoice"><a href="#" class="addIsRock">Rock</a></div>
<div class="scissorsChoice"><a href="#">Scissors</a></div>
<div class="paperChoice"><a href="#">Paper</a></div>
```